# Enabling/Disabling Script in C# failing to work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been developing a 2D platformer game in C# and Unity and as a part of the game I have been developing powerups. One of these in invincibility, so when the player collides with the game object they cannot be killed for a period of time. I am relatively new to Unity and C# and read that I can use '.enabled' to enable/disable an external script that is attached to the same object. However, when I activate the powerup the object is destroyed but if I collide with an enemy or object I still die. Can anyone see why this is happening.

Below is the script that I have developed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class InvincibilityPowerup : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Duration = 15;

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Shield")
        {
            Destroy(GameObject.Find("Invincibility"));

            StartCoroutine("Invincible");
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Invincible()
    {
        Collision pIn = gameObject.GetComponent<Collision>();
        pIn.enabled = false;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Duration);

        pIn.enabled = true;

    }
}
```

Comment: A few notes: 1) All `enabled = false` will do is prevent a behavior's `Update()` from being called; the script will still be there doing everything else it does.  2) Is `Collision` your own script?  Unity already has a class named `Collision` and it's not a behavior so you can't grab it with `GetComponent<T>` and it'll be confusing if you ever need to use both scripts in the same place. 3) If the `GameObject` owning this script is "Invincibility" then it will destroy itself and the coroutine wont run.

Comment: @Foggzie Collision is my own script that I have created. The script that I have shown above is attached to the player and the object that is being destroyed is the sprite that appears in the game. How would I temporarily stop the script called 'Collision' (I plan on renaming this now btw) from running?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.. If you want to delete your question see [How does deletion
  work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) `GameObject.Find` is completely unnecessary here. You already know which object is the invincibility powerup: its the one this script is attached to

2) `Collision pIn = gameObject.GetComponent<Collision>();` both a) doesn't do what you want it to (you want to get the OTHER game object!) b) doesn't work anyway  (`Collision` is not a component, `Collider` is)

3) you're destroying `this` before starting the coroutine, meaning your coroutine is being destroyed too.

Comment: The script that I have shown above is attached to the player, so when I used GameObject.Find it finds the powerup sprite in the game and destroys it to prevent it from being activated again. 'Collision' is a script that I have created that calls a coroutine that kills my player. This is also attached to my player. How would I temporarily disable the 'Collision' script for the duration that I wish too? (Thanks for your help btw)

Comment: Protip: if you are using `GameObject.Find` for any reason, you're doing it wrong. `coll.gameObject` is *already* a reference to your powerup in that case.